# Identifying remote disconnection in socket client

Tags: linux, sockets, zeromq

How do I find out from a socket client program that the remote connection is down (e.g. the server is down). When I do a recv and the server is down it blocks if I do not set any timeout. However in my case I cannot put any reliable timeout value to get around it since otherwise the recv times out even when the server is up but the response really takes longer than the timeout value that I have set.

Comment: What protocol are you using on top of TCP? There is no "one right way" to do this. It depends on the particular protocol you are implementing. Follow the protocol's rules.

Comment: I am using ZeroMQ. I am posing the question in their forum as well to see whether there is such a provision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, ZeroMQ just passes this on to the next layer. So the protocol you are implementing on top of ZeroMQ will have to handle this.

[Heartbeats are recommended.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/5056) Basically, just have one side send a message if the connection is otherwise idle. The other side can treat the absence of such messages as a failure condition and close the connection.

You may wish to modify your higher level protocols to be more robust. For example, you can submit a command, query its status, and allow the other side to forget about the command. That way, if the connection is lost, you can reconnect and query any outstanding commands. Any it doesn't have, you know didn't get through and can resubmit. Once you get a reply with the result of a command, you can tell the other side that it can now forget the response.

This allows you to keep the connection active while a long-running command is ongoing. Every so often you ask, "is everything okay". The other side responds, "yes". You can use [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) where the other side delays responding for a second or so while the command is in process. This allows it to return the results immediately rather than having to wait a second for your next query.

The specifics depend on your exact requirements, but you *must* design this correctly into your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote host goes down without sending you a tcp `FIN` package then you have no chance to detect that. You can test that behaviour by firewalling a port after a connection has been established on that port. Your program will "hang" forever.

However, the Linux kernel supports a mechanism called [TCP keep alives](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) which are meant to close a tcp connection after a given timeout. If you can't specify a timeout for your application, than there isn't a reliable chance to use that. Last chance might be to use features of the application protocol (can you name it?), if that protocol does not support features for connection handling you may *invent* something on your own on top of that.

Comment: If the protocol doesn't address this obvious, well-known and well-understood problem, the protocol is fundamentally broken and should just be discarded.

Comment: I am using ZeroMQ. I am posing the question in their forum as well to see whether there is such a provision.

Comment: Here is there website: http://zeromq.org/ and here is their documentation on API reference: http://api.zeromq.org/ I tried to poke around their TCP KEEP ALIVE options but couldn't figure out much so far.

Comment: @user33804 They formerly suggested exactly the same that I did - using keep alives - but seems that they have implemented a 'heartbeat' feature after that.